# Utility to display select with queries on console

Tags: java, jpa

I'm looking for an utility to run a JPA query and display the query along with its results in console. Just like running a select statement in native sql client:

```
ij> select * from standalonejpa.Emp_PHONE;
EMPLOYEE_ID|PHONE_NUM           |PHONENUMBE&
--------------------------------------------
1          |12938302            |0
```

I would like to write a method that would accept **one parameter - table name** - and **produce above statement** to console by running EntityManager's `createQuery()` and  `getResultList()`. Do you know such utility or I have to carefully craft it  myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the solution that uses JDBC query and pretty print the results with Derbytools utility class. I'm selecting all tables from the JPA project like that:

```
    Connection conn = em.unwrap(Connection.class);
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    for(EntityType<?> et : emf.getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + et.getName();
        System.out.println("> " + query);
        st.execute(query);
        JDBCDisplayUtil.DisplayResults(System.out, st, conn);
    }
```

As a result I have pretty formatted results like:

```
> SELECT * FROM Employee
ID         
-----------
1          
51
```

Here comes the information to keep completeness of this post:
I used [EclipseLink `java.sql.Connection` unwrapping](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager) and added to my pom.xml dependency to Derbytools:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
        <version>10.10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Actually you can use pretty-printing from Derbytools with any database, not only Apache Derby.
The whole hassle I make was to create a "testing" project for JPA mappings, that will be displaying generated tables along with data in there. The whole project is called "jpa-testing" and it is available from [my github](https://github.com/zbigniewTomczak/jpa-testing).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a utility, but you can enable logging to show the resulting SQL.

As for crafting one, I would create a listener that interfaces with EclipseLink's logger to capture the log output then display it on the screen.

You can send JPA queries directly through the persistence layer, the only thing you can't do (or can't do easily) at runtime is adding new classes as the JPA enabled classes have to be known at startup.  Though there should be an implementation specific way to register new JPA classes at runtime.

Comment: I was aware of logging functionalities of of JPA providers. I'm looking for something more human readable though. I wouldn't go for proposed solution because it would require not only formatting query results but parsing the logs first. I'm currently considering marrying pretty printing JDBC statements from Derbytools with proxy spying on JDBC driver with log4jdbc.